# Multi-Threading and Migrations in EF (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have been using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` as the database initializer in order to use `Seed` method with migrations.

In order to learn more about DBinitializers in EF I had a look at [this](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/) blog post. I don't know this post is still relevant for EF6 or not, but gives a good overview I think.

After making a research on thread-safety and possible race conditions for database initialization, I have some questions about the thread-safety and consistency of database initialization and seeding.

1) First of all database initialization is thread safe or not? I am using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and creating multiple threads in the same AppDomain (each thread creates a new DbContext). When I start the application first of these threads should initialize the database (and also seed it for the first time in an AppDomain I think). In that case any race condition is possible between the different threads in the same AppDomain? Initialization is said to be thread safe in a single AppDomain?

2) Also, is it a good practice to call `SaveChanges()` in the `Seed` method more than one time. For ex: I have a normalized database which contains many tables connected with other by foreign keys. If I seed each table one by one and calling `SaveChanges()` on each of them in the same table, is it possible to cause any trouble. For ex. is it possible for another `IDbInitializer` in another AppDomain to populate these tables at the same time?

3) As far as I understood `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` runs the `Seed` method once per each AppDomain. So, it means even in the same application, each new AppDomain instance will try to Seed the same database which may be a performance bottleneck I think. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Good questions! I've regularly seen errors during startup after adding new migrations that point towards multiple instances of the migrations being run concurrently. If this is indeed the case, I wonder how to fix it. Perhaps by locking around a dummy query to the database...